# trouble correcting a sub-query

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have a sub-query being used as a parameter in a report.  This particular query was being used in another report so I was trying to be clever and use it again for this report.  The way the client wants it done, they need a current month and YTD for both the last year and current year per a respective item.  I think I have the current month figured out however, my issue is that something is getting replaced for transaction date or category.  Below is the example

```
(
  customer,
  fiscalperiod,
  transactiondate,
  workcenter,
  projectid,
  eventname,
  sales,
  directlabor,
  materialscost,
  othercost,
  subcontractor,
  cogs,
  projectprofit,
  projectprofitmargin
)
AS 
 SELECT b.customer, b.fiscalperiod, b.workcenter AS transactiondate, b.projectid AS workcenter, b.eventname AS projectid, b.sales AS eventname, b.directlabor AS sales, b.materialscost AS directlabor, b.othercost AS materialscost, b.subcontractor AS othercost, b.transactiondate AS subcontractor, 
        CASE
            WHEN b.cogs > 1::double precision THEN b.cogs * (- 1::double precision)
            ELSE b.cogs
        END AS cogs, b.projectprofit, b.projectprofitmargin
   FROM ( SELECT table1.customer, table1.fiscalperiod, table1.workcenter, table1.projectid, table1.eventname, sum(table1.revenue) AS sales, sum(table1.directlabor) AS directlabor, sum(table1.materialscost) AS materialscost, sum(table1.othercost) AS othercost, sum(table1.subcontractor) AS subcontractor, table1.transactiondate, 
                CASE
                    WHEN sum(table1.expense) < 0::double precision THEN sum(table1.expense) * (- 1::double precision)
                    ELSE sum(table1.expense)
                END AS cogs, sum(table1.revenue) - 
                CASE
                    WHEN sum(table1.expense) < 0::double precision THEN sum(table1.expense) * (- 1::double precision)
                    ELSE sum(table1.expense)
                END AS projectprofit, 
                CASE
                    WHEN sum(table1.revenue) = NULL::double precision THEN 100::double precision
                    WHEN sum(table1.revenue) = 0::double precision THEN 100::double precision
                    ELSE 100::double precision * (sum(table1.revenue) + sum(table1.expense)) / sum(table1.revenue)
                END AS projectprofitmargin
           FROM ( SELECT p.customer, p.projectid, p.eventname, t.fiscalperiod, w.workcenter, t.transactiondate, 
                        CASE
                            WHEN c."type"::text = 'RV'::character varying::text THEN sum(
                            CASE
                                WHEN t.namount = 0.00::double precision THEN 0.00::double precision
                                ELSE t.namount
                            END)
                            ELSE 0.00::double precision
                        END AS revenue, 
                        CASE
                            WHEN c."type"::text = 'EX'::character varying::text THEN sum(
                            CASE
                                WHEN t.namount = 0.00::double precision THEN 0.00::double precision
                                ELSE t.namount
                            END)
                            ELSE 0.00::double precision
                        END AS expense, 
                        CASE
                            WHEN t.glaccount::text = '40020'::character varying::text THEN sum(
                            CASE
                                WHEN t.namount = 0.00::double precision THEN 0.00::double precision
                                ELSE t.namount
                            END)
                            ELSE 0.00::double precision
                        END AS directlabor, 
                        CASE
                            WHEN t.glaccount::text = '40000'::character varying::text THEN sum(
                            CASE
                                WHEN t.namount = 0.00::double precision THEN 0.00::double precision
                                ELSE t.namount
                            END)
                            ELSE 0.00::double precision
                        END AS materialscost, 
                        CASE
                            WHEN t.glaccount::text = '46200'::character varying::text THEN sum(
                            CASE
                                WHEN t.namount = 0.00::double precision THEN 0.00::double precision
                                ELSE t.namount
                            END)
                            WHEN t.glaccount::text = '40112'::character varying::text THEN sum(
                            CASE
                                WHEN t.namount = 0.00::double precision THEN 0.00::double precision
                                ELSE t.namount
                            END)
                            ELSE 0.00::double precision
                        END AS othercost, 
                        CASE
                            WHEN t.glaccount::text = '40030'::character varying::text THEN sum(
                            CASE
                                WHEN t.namount = 0.00::double precision THEN 0.00::double precision
                                ELSE t.namount
                            END)
                            ELSE 0.00::double precision
                        END AS subcontractor
                   FROM hargrade_projectlink.twprojecttransaction t
              LEFT JOIN hargrade_projectlink.vsproject p ON t.projectid::text = p.projectid::text
         LEFT JOIN hargrade_projectlink.vsworkcenter w ON t.workcenterid::text = w.id::text
    LEFT JOIN hargrade_projectlink.vscategory c ON t.categoryid::text = c.id::text
   WHERE p.customer::text <> ''::character varying::text AND t.batchtype::text <> 'BDGT'::character varying::text
   GROUP BY p.customer, p.eventname, p.projectid, t.fiscalperiod, w.workcenter, c."type", t.glaccount, t.transactiondate) table1
          GROUP BY table1.customer, table1.fiscalperiod, table1.workcenter, table1.eventname, table1.projectid, table1.transactiondate) b
  WHERE b.sales > 0::double precision;


Select sales,transactiondate
from public.vw_ytdprojectdetailfinal_copy
where transactiondate >= date_trunc('month', current_date - interval '1' month)
  and transactiondate < date_trunc('month', current_date

the desired:                  the actual:
sales  transactiondate        sales  transactiondate 
num      2018-05-08             0     account services
num      2018-05-08             0     sales
num      2018-05-08             0     other department
num      2018-05-08
num      2018-05-08
num      2018-05-08


any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is b.workcenter?  I see you are aliasing that as the transaction date here and it seems to be workcenter/dept names.

```
SELECT b.customer, b.fiscalperiod, b.workcenter AS transactiondate
```

Comment: work center is location names, like where the work centers actually are

Comment: I think your aliases are wrong if that is the case. What does this view look like vw_ytdprojectdetailfinal_copy?

Comment: ya that's what happened, I was copying this cover from another view, and trying to add the transactiondate, not sure what happened, but it aliased all the b. columns.  I appreciate you taking the time.  I ended up making another copy and it didn't alias those columns.  Not too sure what caused in the first place, but again thank you